# k-dimension Ord's typeclass with haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to implement function which takes two objects, all I want to know about this objects that them can be thought as values with fields and I want compare coresponding fields. (no matter what the fields and their types)

So I want to implement polymorthic function c which takes two values of same polymorphic type each of this values has N fields and corresponding fields has same type, also all fields are instances of Ord. So I want compare corresponding fields and build a list of Bools

```
c :: KD o => o -> o -> [Bool]
c o1 o2 = (\n -> (kth o1 n) == (kth o2 n) ) <$> [1..dimensions o1]

class KD c where
  dimensions :: c -> Int
  kth :: (Ord ?) => c -> Int -> ?
  
-- for example pair can be used as object with 2 dimensions 
instance (Ord a, Ord b, Show a, Show b) => KD (a,b) where
    dimensions _ = 2
    kth (a,_) 1 = undefined -- "I want a here"
    kth (_,b) 2 = undefined -- "I want b here"
```

I am stucked with KD typeclass and instance implementation, how can I achive this in Haskell ?

ps.
Also i'am thinking about mapping each object to a list of Ints and then deal with compare Ints, but I don't know can I achive such a mapping for any type such as String, List etc..

```
class KDI c where
  map_ :: c -> [Integer]
```

Comment: Can you give some more examples of what concrete types you would want to make an instance of `KD`? If all you want to know about each field of the data structure is that it is an instance of `Ord`, you can try using an [existentially quantified](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/existential_quantification.html) list

Comment: It can be any type which contain some fields, for example pair or triple.. or Data Men = Men String Int Int - Men with name, age and height, I try existential for fixing type in kth function, but catch a problem with implementing Ord instance for this type...

Comment: You may want this https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/generics.html

Comment: “Vector” is definitely not a fitting term for this. Vectors are always homogeneous. (IMO vectors aren't containers at all but abstractly elements of a vector space, and only the representation of them in an arbitrary basis is the array that people call “vector”.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout I change "Vector" -> "values with fields"

Answer (score 3):

I realized that I can move comparsion inside typeclass like this

```
class KD c where
  dimensions :: c -> Int
  cmp_kth :: c -> c -> Int -> Ordering

instance (Ord a, Ord b) => KD (a,b) where
    dimensions _ = 2
    cmp_kth (a,_) (a',_) 0 = compare a a'
    cmp_kth (_,b) (_,b') 1 = compare b b'
    cmp_kth _ _ n = error $ "to big index from kth " ++ show n

data Men = Men {name::String,age::Int,height::Int} deriving Show
instance KD Men where
  dimensions _ = 3
  cmp_kth (Men n _ _) (Men n' _ _) 0 = compare n n'
  cmp_kth (Men _ n _) (Men _ n' _) 1 = compare n n'
  cmp_kth (Men _ _ n) (Men _ _ n') 2 = compare n n'

--cmp_kth (Men "J" 1 2) (Men "J" 2 2) 2

c :: KD o => o -> o -> [Bool]
c o1 o2 = (\n -> (cmp_kth o1 o2 n) == EQ ) <$> [0..(dimensions o1)-1]
```

And now can compare any "field enumerated objects" in an abstract way:

```
*Main> c (1,2) (3,2)
[False,True]
*Main> c (Men "J" 1 2) (Men "J" 2 2)
[True,False,True]
```

Also this typeclass can be used to [implement abstract k-d tree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYxOabjYWgc&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Please always use 0-based indexing conventions (even though tuples' “indexing” with `fst` and `snd` is in a sense 1-based).

Comment: @leftaroundabout, fixed, thnx!)